# Unable to display iplot visualization on google colab

Tags: python, plotly, google-colaboratory, visualize

I'm trying to visualize my data, I have import pandas and plotly. The problem is it run normal but no visual show up. Here is the code

All the librarys I import:

```
%matplotlib inline

from math import sqrt
from numpy import concatenate
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.tools as tls
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

py.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
```

Import data:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer="data.csv", index_col="Date")
```

And convert to timedate:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
```

And yet when I try to visualize the data nothing show up

```
btc_trace = go.Scatter(x=data.index, y=data['Volume'], name= 'Price')
py.iplot([btc_trace])
```

Comment: I do not know what version you are currently using, but you can specify a renderer to make it viewable. I checked with the example in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-plots-on-date-axes). Also see [here](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/#setting-the-default-renderer) for more information on renderers.

Comment: `import plotly.offline as py;import plotly.graph_objs as go;import plotly.express as px;import plotly.io as pio;pio.renderers.default = "colab";data = px.data.stocks();
btc_trace = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=data.index, y=data['GOOG'], name= 'google'))
py.iplot(btc_trace)`